# Docker for C# core (linux type) behavior - Related to image build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am writting C# core with dockers (based on linux containers).

In every image, I need to compile + running.

As I understand, I need two images, one for compile and one for run-time.
Respectively microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk and microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime

I am using docker-compose, which looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  TestDock:
    image: test_dock
    volumes:
     - c:/my_data_folder:/data:rw
    build:
      context: ./my_projects/TestDock/
      dockerfile: TestDock/Dockerfile
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:
    FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
    WORKDIR /app

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY TestDock/TestDock.csproj TestDock/

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish TestDock.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestDock.dll"]
```

Everything is fine, but:

1. I need to include images microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime and microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk.

For production, I need only the runtime, and without source. It's huge docker (over 500M) - Is it normal?

Clarification: The image size reflects on the size of the file and the size when it is running.

> docker save my_image > my_image.tar

This is a one size.

> docker-compose run my_image

When the docker is running - it may hold some disk space, and memory - How can I check that out?

I need the most minimal size of docker.

Can I split my docker to two dockers?
Also how can I use "docker-compose build" command with a specific docker?

2. In some computers, the build take very long time (more than 15 minutes), but I have many projects, so every fix may take long time.

Why it may take too long time in some computers (1 minute good vs 15 minutes bad) - What can I check? Are many dockers installed may cause low performance?

3. Can I control which user is running every image? What can I do about?
4. How can I debug docker in a debugger (is any for C# core)? - Not just logs.

Thanks.

Comment: @Etian you you have multiple questions here and you will need to break you questions apart into different SO questions to ensure each question receives proper attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have multiple questions and you should break them apart into different SO questsions, I am going to try and address two simply.

You are following the Docker [multi-stage builds](https://medium.com/@chrislewisdev/optimizing-your-net-core-docker-image-size-with-multi-stage-builds-778c577121d) pattern that you shared. This means that you have already reduced your runtime container to it's smallest size (broadly speaking) for a .NET Core app. You can delete the .NET Core SDK image from the Production server but it really shouldn't be on your Production server in the first place. You should be building your image on a build server, the production server just needs to pull the latest image.

Regarding, your other question: about Nuget packages. You should be working with an internet connection when pulling the latest Nuget packages. If you are doing this on a production server and the internet connection is a vulnerability, again use a build server.

Comment: If I use the SDK for build - it has some disk space. Can I delete it after doing publish?

Comment: You will not want to delete the SDK image probably. It will be used as the FROM for some image that you will use for building your app each time you make code changes.

Comment: You mean the container doesn't hold an image copy. The image that takes space on disk is outside the container?

Comment: Well any Docker container is run base on a Docker image, and any Docker image can be based on other images. The images layers to any single Docker image need to remain they are dependencies. You can always run the cmd "docker image prune" to delete any unused images

Comment: I don't want to delete it - The container itself may hold lot of unnecessary data. I should have only the runtime on production. Why should I have also the compiler. docker image prune - I don't think inside the docker build I can. What may happen to microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk image (I still want to keep it, but not in the container, because it is on production, which I don't need that image).

Comment: Well. For the size of container - I see the blog https://medium.com/@chrislewisdev/optimizing-your-net-core-docker-image-size-with-multi-stage-builds-778c577121d , that illustrate that only the last image will take place. For Q5 I see that JetBrain may be good, but I didn't see it yet. For Q2 - I need some way not always using the internet gor nuget, so I need a shortcut for that.

Comment: @Eitan I have updated my answer to hopefully better assist you.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I don't know if it's good to break apart my question - They are all related to compilation on docker, and may be one big question. I have one 'common' project which used all the nuget in other project. I created an image from that, and instead I add a reference to the image. Add a copy line before publish (I will described it in my question), and in publish add --no-references and --no-dependencies. Still, my code cannot be build.

Comment: @Eitan, this yet another question or problem, you have not mentioned your code not building before in your original question, you do have way to many questions and they simply will not get addressed and unless you do a better job of clarifying and distilling each problem down into smaller SO questions, if they are related, reference the questions with links

Comment: I thought about spliting to two compilation after this discussion. I cannot wait and sit. Most of the qustion already solved, except the second one. I don't know if it's better I answer those questions in body. They are all so other, but also so related